# ScheduledExecutorService with min & max number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to use ScheduledExecutorService to schedule tasks on a given thread pool.

```
public ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService() {
    return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);
}
```

It looks like this way of creating an instance assumes a user-specified value as a minimum number of threads and the maximum number of threads will be `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (default value).

How can I specify the maximum number of threads for an instance of ScheduledExecutorService? I can't allocate such a huge number of threads as a maximum number of threads.

Code snippets in a sequence from the decompiled jar -

```
// From Executors.java
public static ScheduledExecutorService newScheduledThreadPool(int corePoolSize) {
    return new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize);
}

// From ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java
public ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize) {
    super(corePoolSize, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
          DEFAULT_KEEPALIVE_MILLIS, MILLISECONDS,
          new DelayedWorkQueue());
}

// From ThreadPoolExecutor.java
public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,
                          int maximumPoolSize,
                          long keepAliveTime,
                          TimeUnit unit,
                          BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
    this(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue,
         Executors.defaultThreadFactory(), defaultHandler);
}
```

If I'm missing to refer a method in Java doc, please point me to the correct location. TIA.

Comment: *corePoolSize - the number of threads to keep in the pool* - why do you think this means minimum?

Comment: Updated my post with the code snippet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Constructor` of `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` does not directly provide the setting of this parameter. You can manually call `setMaximumPoolSize` method:

```
    public ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService() {
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduledThreadPoolExecutor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize);
        scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.setMaximumPoolSize(xxx);
        return scheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
    }
```

**But setting this `maximumPoolSize` is meaningless in `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` , which is why the constructor does not declare this parameter.**

From Java doc of `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` :

> While this class inherits from ThreadPoolExecutor, a few of the inherited tuning methods are not useful for it. In particular, because it acts as a fixed-sized pool using corePoolSize threads and an unbounded queue, adjustments to maximumPoolSize have no useful effect. Additionally, it is almost never a good idea to set corePoolSize to zero or use allowCoreThreadTimeOut because this may leave the pool without threads to handle tasks once they become eligible to run.

More details, see `delayedExecute` and `ensurePrestart` in `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, `maximumPoolSize` is useless.

```
   private void delayedExecute(RunnableScheduledFuture<?> task) {
        if (isShutdown())
            reject(task);
        else {
            // add task to queue
            super.getQueue().add(task);
            if (isShutdown() &&
                !canRunInCurrentRunState(task.isPeriodic()) &&
                remove(task))
                task.cancel(false);
            else
                ensurePrestart();
        }
    }

    void ensurePrestart() {
        int wc = workerCountOf(ctl.get());
        if (wc < corePoolSize)
            addWorker(null, true);
        else if (wc == 0)
            addWorker(null, false);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, got it. But how can I restrict the number of threads in a pool. Any other way that you would like to recommend? My goal is to schedule tasks on a thread pool of which I can control min and max threads.

Comment: In ```ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor ```,  the maximum number of threads is ```corePoolSize```,  this is why the ```maximumPoolSize``` parameter is meaningless.  In other words, you can only have a maximum of ```corePoolSize``` threads performing your scheduled task and remaining tasks are put into an unbounded queue. So, set ```corePoolSize``` is enough. @Swapnil

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.